# Cannot "Use Default Gradle Wrapper"

Tags: android, gradle, settings

I want to check "Use Default Gradle Wrapper" but cant find this setting in the latest version of Android Studio.
This is what Im getting in the settings
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should already be all set: the Gradle version used by the Gradle Wrapper of a build is defined by the `gradle-wrapper.properties` file. When Android Studio is configured to use Gradle from this file, then that means that the default Gradle Wrapper for the project is used.

Comment: But I want to use that setting anyway since Im getting while running a basic app and the guides tell me to change something from that setting

Comment: You _are_ already using that setting: “Use Default Gradle Wrapper” is the same as “Use Gradle from: 'gradle-wrapper.properties' file”. Or maybe I misunderstand you? In that case, please clarify your question with more details like error messages and exact steps to reproduce.